# Unable to pass file and text from jsp to servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

hello i am new to web project, i want to pass a file  and also a text field to a servlet.I could upload file successfully but can't pass text variable into servlet ,it shows null when i try to print.

```
<div id="view2">
  <b>Upload new Timetable</b>
  <fieldset>
    <h3> Choose File to Upload in Server </h3>
    <form action="FileUploadHandler" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="class_name" id=nam/> 
      <input type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    </form>          
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please, post your servlet code ?

Comment: [vishal gajeria]   I edited my code like this String description = request.getParameter("class_name");                                                     Part filePart = request.getPart("file");                                                   String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();..... i also added annotation...@MultipartConfig(
  fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,
  maxFileSize=1024*1024*50 ,
  maxRequestSize=1024*1024*100
  
  )